# Producer/Consumer High performance UDP packet capture/sniffing in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp

I am struggling a UDP packet sniffing program which shall capture packets as efficient as wireshark. What I simply do is opening a UDP socket with highest thread priority to capture packets from 192.168.2.20 over port 5001.

After quite a few of trials (sending a couple of seconds of UDP transmission from another computer which has 192.168.2.20 interface on port 5001 using iperf), I come up with the solution of producer/consumer multithreaded program under c++. My objection is to printout the size and the identification number of received packet until the transmission ends (the program will run for weeks).

So, I use the producer buffer as a queue to capture received UDP packets until reaching a queue limit (i.e. 40000). After the limit is achieved, the producer copies its content into another queue buffer and clears its content to continue receiving UDP packets which consumer thread will utilizes so that no thread synchronization will be needed. However, my program does not work perfectly. Below is my code. How can I achieve my goal (printing out total number of received UDP packets and its identification numbers more efficiently)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <numeric>
using namespace std;

const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
#define ETH_DATA_LEN 1512
#define UDP 0x11
#define SRC_ADDR "192.168.2.20"
mutex m;
mutex m_print;

bool is_qq_empty = true;
bool is_transmission_continue = true;
bool is_producer_started = false;
struct ReceiveBufferArray {
    uint8_t buf[ETH_DATA_LEN];
    int id;
    time_t time;
    int index;
};
vector<int> packetSize;
vector<int> consume_buffer;
vector<int> loss_buffer;
vector<std::time_t> time_buffer;
std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> qq;

std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> qq_copy;
int gmSocket;

struct sockaddr_in gmClientAddr;
struct sockaddr_in gmServerAddr;

socklen_t gmClientLen = sizeof(gmServerAddr);

int openSocket(const std::string &IpAddress, int Port)
{
    int ret;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int optval = 1;

    gmSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (gmSocket < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "cannot Open datagram socket!! Ip: " << IpAddress << " - Port " << std::to_string(Port) << std::endl;

        return -1;
    }
    /* Bind our local address so that the client can send to us */
    gmServerAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    gmServerAddr.sin_addr.s_addr =INADDR_ANY;
    gmServerAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

    timeout.tv_sec = 10;// timeout for 10seconds
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    setsockopt(gmSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeout));
    setsockopt(gmSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &optval, sizeof(optval));
    setsockopt(gmSocket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof(optval));
    std::cout << "Socket has been opened. Ip: " << IpAddress << " - Port " << std::to_string(Port) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

void clear(std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> &q)
{
    std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> empty;
    std::swap(q,empty);
}


std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> copy_queue(std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray> &q)
{
    std::queue<ReceiveBufferArray>Q2 =q;
    return Q2;
}

void consumer_thread()
{

    struct sockaddr_in source_socket_address, dest_socket_address;
    memset(&source_socket_address, 0, sizeof(source_socket_address));
    memset(&dest_socket_address, 0, sizeof(dest_socket_address));
    uint8_t ethernet_data[ETH_DATA_LEN];

    int old_val = 99999;
    bool start_copying_flag = false;
    while (is_transmission_continue || qq_copy.empty())
    {

        if (!qq_copy.empty())
        {
            start_copying_flag = true;
            // Record start time

            m.lock();

            std::copy(std::begin(qq_copy.front().buf),std::end(qq_copy.front().buf), std::begin(ethernet_data));
            qq_copy.pop();

            m.unlock();


            struct iphdr *ip_packet = (struct iphdr *)ethernet_data;

            if((ip_packet->saddr == inet_addr(SRC_ADDR)) && (ip_packet->protocol == UDP))
            {
                consume_buffer.push_back(ntohs(ip_packet->id));


                std::cout << "id: " << std::to_string(ntohs(ip_packet->id))
                << ", Packet Number: " << std::to_string(consume_buffer.size())<<endl;


            }
            usleep(1);

        }else if(qq_copy.empty() && start_copying_flag)
        {
            if(qq.size()>0)
            {
                m.lock();//##################################################3
                qq_copy = copy_queue(qq);
                clear(qq);
                m.unlock();//##################################################3
            }

        }
    }
}



void producer_thread()
{
    int packet_size;

    openSocket(SRC_ADDR,5001);
    ReceiveBufferArray _rbuf;

    int counter = 0;

    while (is_transmission_continue)
    {
        packet_size = recvfrom(gmSocket , _rbuf.buf , ETH_DATA_LEN , 0 , NULL, NULL);

        if (qq.size() < 40000)
        {

            counter++;

            m.lock();
            qq.push(_rbuf);
            m.unlock();
            std::cout <<"Packet Size : " << counter << endl;

        }else {
            std::cout << "PRODUCER EMPTY" << endl;
            m.lock();//##################################################3
            qq_copy = copy_queue(qq);
            m.unlock();//##################################################3
            clear(qq);
            is_producer_started = true;

        }

        if((packet_size < 0) && is_producer_started){
            is_transmission_continue =false;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "PRODUCER DONE" << endl;
}



int main()
{

    setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, -20);
    thread cons(consumer_thread);
    thread prod(producer_thread);

    prod.join();
    cons.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "my program does not work perfectly" what does that mean? what is your question?

Comment: Meaning that the program miss UDP packets while wireshark does not (15% loss). I need ~100% successfully delivered packets ratio. My program completes printing the output out after a while later (20-30sec) for 10seconds of udp transmission delivery (iperf -c 192.168.2.20 -u -b100M -i1)

Comment: udp and "need 100% sucessfully delivered packets" usually doesnt go well together. Typically you'd use udp when loss of single packets is acceptable

Comment: I expressed my comments with some absence,  sorry. I tried to infer 100% success to provide the same packet delivery ratio with wireshark. Assumingly, some packet loss is expected due to lossy nature of UDP. That is why, I need to use UDP over TCP to comply my goal. So, because of not maintaining the multithread producer/consumer structure well, I cannot capture the UDP packets as wireshark does.

Comment: As long as the internal OS buffer doesn't fill, you shouldn't be missing any packets that the network card receives. Your program is "missing" packets because you are not using locks correctly with your data structures and you have data races in your code. You should consider if it is really necessary to use multithreading. It's probably fast enough single threaded (write to the file every time you get a packet). If you do have to use multithreading, look up existing producer/consumer examples. Mutexes are not sufficient for prod/cons. I expect to see condition variables or semaphores.